# Pintar filas de la tabla

Tags: javascript

Quiero pintar algunas filas de la tabla, es posible hacer esto?

me refiero a poner una condición para que se pinte:

`if(Object.values(totalDatos[j])[i].tipoUser=='verdadero'`

```
    html += "<td if(Object.values(totalDatos[j])[i].tipoUser=='verdadero')
{style.background-color=yellow} >" + Object.values(totalDatos[j])[i] + "</td>";
```

ejemplo:

```js
let condicion = true;


var html = "<table border=2 id='examples'>";
html += "<thead>";
html += "<tr><th colspan='3'>Validacion </th></tr>";
html += "<tr>";

html += "<th style='background-color=yellow;'> intento </th>";
html += "<th > Usuario </th>";
html += "<th > Resultado </th></tr> </thead>";

document.getElementById("tablaVariablesSVM").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="tablaVariablesSVM"></div>
```

Comment: HTML es un lenguaje de marcado no puedes añadir esa lógica. Lo lógico sería hacer el if antes de la asignación a tu variable "html". Si cumple la condición añadir el td con una clase o el estilo inline y si no añadirla sin el estilo.

Comment: @Kiko_L es javascript

Comment: Pero estás metiendo una condición dentro de un <td>, que es HTML. A eso se refiere.

Comment: Correcto, y la respuesta que te han dado es a lo que me refería.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basandome en tu condicion if, reacomode la forma en que asignas la informacion a la variable `html`.

Prueba con esto:

```
if(Object.values(totalDatos[j])[i].tipoUser=='verdadero')
{
    html += "<td style='background-color:yellow;'>" + Object.values(totalDatos[j])[i] + "</td>";
}
```

Si te fijas la condicion no puede ir dentro del html, por eso hay que sacarla hacia arriba y cuando se cumpla, entonces armas el html. Me supongo que estas usando javascript.

***Actualizando***

Ten presente esto:

```
html += "<td style='background-color:yellow;'>" + Object.values(totalDatos[j])[i].xxx + "</td>";
```

Donde xxx es la propiedad que quieres mostrar en la celda.

Comment: si cumple la condicion pero no pinta

Comment: `html += "<td style='background-color=yellow;'>" + Object.values(totalDatos[j])[i].propiedad_ha_mostrar + "</td>";` debes de colocar que propiedad quieres mostrar en la celda.

Comment: si muestra la propiedad pero no pinta

Comment: he editado mi pregunta con un ejemplo

Comment: muestra el contenido completo de la variable `html`, para ver como se esta armando la tabla.

Comment: @hubman e actualizado el ejemplo del atributo style de los td, revisa nuevamente.

Answer (score 1):

Si utilizas las tablas de bootstrap puedes cambiar el color manipulando las clases:

```
if(Object.values(totalDatos[j])[i].tipoUser=='verdadero')
{
   $('#id_del_tr').addClass('table-warning');
}
```

Tambien lo puedes hacer con los  th o td.

Comment: puedes  modificar mi ejemplo con tu respuesta porfavor.

Answer (score 1):

```
let condicion = true;


var html = "<table class="table" border=2 id='examples'>";
html += "<thead>";
html += "<tr><th colspan='3'>Validacion </th></tr>";
html += "<tr>";
if(condicion){
   html += "<th class='table-warning'> intento </th>";
}else{
    html += "<th> intento </th>";
}

html += "<th > Usuario </th>";
html += "<th > Resultado </th></tr> </thead>";

document.getElementById("tablaVariablesSVM").innerHTML = html;

<div id="tablaVariablesSVM"></div>
```

Solo si utilizas la tabla de bootstrap.